# How to paraphrase a paraphrased part?

Tags: writing

Lets assume that A wrote an article in 1999 and A included a part taken from B's source written in 1998. How do I paraphrase that part, and how do I cite it?

> Like this; Blablablablabla blabla (A, 1999).
>
> Or like this; Blablablabla blabla (B, 1998).
>
> Or something different?

Comment: Why not just quote B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include both?

Blablabla  (A, 1999, and B, 1998).

Comment: Is it the standard way of citing? I am not really interested in Academic Writing, but I have to write an assay talking about a topic's challenges and measurements in the final exam of a course. I just want to be sure that I won't end up writing something marked by plagiarism. @Regel

Comment: If you cite rigorously, it's not plagiarism. Just mark clearly where you use other people's ideas (by citing), and where you write direct quotes of other people's work (explanation + quotes + citation).

Comment: Citation does not require a quotation, but quotation does require citation.

Comment: Wetlab Walter has it right. I was just trying to say that quotes neet to be clearly marked as quotes.